# Upload file with with arabic file name

Tags: php, file, upload, arabic

I am trying to upload file that have arabic name with php code

```
echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"],"images/artimgs/".$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
```

but the name of the file in the folder "artimgs" when the file is uploaded it appear like this : ط­ط³ط§ظ†.jpg

I want that the file after the upload will have the same name in arabic of the initial file.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1019306

Comment: do not EVER use this code. you are opening your server to a total remote compromise. Nothing says a malicious user can't name `['name']` be `../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

**Answering your question as-is:**

You might check the form page encoding, it probably is windows-1256, it must be utf-8 in both the page where you submit this form, and the page when you display the file name.

**Saying my opinion on the code:**

You might specify the filename your self, as [Marc B] suggested.

Comment: I just change the encoding of the page but i have the same result ,

Comment: Either I try to encode the name of the file before that I upload it like this :
$imgn=utf8_encode($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
$imgtmp=utf8_encode($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]);
echo move_uploaded_file($imgtmp,"images/artimgs/".$imgn);
but I have the same result

Comment: Could you please paste the form page code here, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Either I try to encode the name of the file before that I upload it like this :`$imgn=utf8_encode($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
$imgtmp=utf8_encode($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]);
echo move_uploaded_file($imgtmp,"images/artimgs/".$imgn);`

but i have the same result

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
/* PHP Internal Encoding */
define('PHP_ENC', 'UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding(PHP_ENC);
ini_set('default_charset', PHP_ENC);
```

Comment: I put this and I have the same result

Comment: if you're on a unix like machine you might check the internal encoding for your OS as well.

Comment: no i am using a windows xp , maybe when i upload the site to the server and i use a linux machine the issue will resolve ?